# Service Worker not working on offline mode on IOS 12

Tags: ios, caching, service-worker, offline, progressive-web-apps

I'm trying to make a PWA to work on both online/offline modes on both iOS/Android OS, so far I already got my service worker ready and working on android, is service offline page correctly, but on IOS it's not working at all, I can add my PWA to home screen and it works all IndexedDB methods I have, but once I go offline, it tells me Safari doesn't have internet connection, I think there might be a problem on install method of my service worker, but I have no clue how to check that on iphone since I'm developing on linux, here's my service worker code which work ok on android but not on IOS.

```
(function() {
'use strict';
  var filesToCache = [
    '/app/inicio',
    '/app/mapa',
    '/app/visita',
    '/app/sincronizacion',
    '/static/base/bs4/js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js',
    '/static/base/bs4/css/heineken-bs.min.css',
    '/static/base/bs4/js/bootstrap.min.js',
    '/static/base/bs/js/bootstrap-switch.min.js',
    '/static/base/fontawesome-5.3.1/js/all.min.js', 
    '/static/base/js/chainedfk.js',
    '/static/base/multiselect/js/jquery.multi-select.js',
    '/static/base/js/common.js',
    '/static/base/js/jquery.numeric.min.js',
    '/static/base/bs4/js/popper.min.js',
    '/static/base/bs/css/bootstrap-switch.min.css',
    '/static/base/imgs/favicon/favicon.ico',
    '/static/base/imgs/favicon/ms-icon-144x144.png',
    '/static/base/leaflet-1.3.4/leaflet.css',
    '/static/base/leaflet-1.3.4/leaflet.js',
    '/static/base/bs4/css/map-styles.css',
    '/static/base/leaflet-usermarker-master/src/leaflet.usermarker.js',
    '/static/base/leaflet-usermarker-master/src/leaflet.usermarker.css',
    '/static/base/Leaflet.markercluster-master/dist/leaflet.markercluster-src.js',
    '/static/base/Leaflet.markercluster-master/dist/MarkerCluster.css',
    '/static/base/leaflet-draw/src/leaflet.draw.css',
    '/static/base/leaflet-draw/src/Leaflet.draw.js',
    '/static/base/drag/jquery.sortable.min.js',
    '/static/base/date-time/js/moment-locale.min.js',
    '/static/base/date-time/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js',
    '/static/base/date-time/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css',
    '/static/base/select-picker/css/select-picker.css',
    '/static/base/select-picker/js/select-picker.min.js',
    '/static/base/js/turf.min.js',
    '/static/base/js/util_v1.js',
    '/static/base/js/util_db_v1.js',
    '/static/base/localForage/localforage.min.js',
    '/static/base/localForage/localforage-getitems.js',
    '/static/base/localForage/localforage-setitems.js',
    '/static/base/localForage/localforage-startswith.js',
    '/static/base/js/progressbar.js',
    '/static/base/js/util_db_v1.js',
    '/static/base/js/moment.min.js',
    '/static/base/imgs/puntos/rojo.png',
    '/static/base/imgs/puntos/verde.png',
    '/static/base/imgs/puntos/amarillo.png',
    '/static/base/imgs/puntos/azul.png',
    '/static/base/leaflet.offline/dist/bundle.js',
    '/static/base/imgs/favicon/favicon-16x16.png',
    '/static/base/imgs/favicon/favicon-32x32.png',
    '/static/base/imgs/favicon/favicon-96x96.png',
    '/static/base/imgs/favicon/apple-icon-57x57.png',
    '/static/base/imgs/favicon/apple-icon-60x60.png',
    '/static/base/imgs/favicon/apple-icon-72x72.png',
    '/static/base/imgs/favicon/apple-icon-76x76.png',
    '/static/base/imgs/favicon/apple-icon-114x114.png',
    '/static/base/imgs/favicon/apple-icon-120x120.png',
    '/static/base/imgs/favicon/apple-icon-144x144.png',
    '/static/base/imgs/favicon/apple-icon-152x152.png',
    '/static/base/imgs/favicon/apple-icon-180x180.png',
    '/static/base/imgs/favicon/android-icon-192x192.png',
  ];
  var staticCacheName = 'pages-cache-v5';
  self.addEventListener('install', function(event) {
    event.waitUntil(
      caches.open(staticCacheName)
      .then(function(cache) {
        return cache.addAll(filesToCache);
      })
    );
  });
  self.addEventListener('fetch', function(event) {
    if (event.request.url.match( '^.*(\/app\/).*$' ) || event.request.url.match( '^.*(\/app/inicio\/).*$' ) || event.request.url.match( '^.*(\/app/sincronizacion\/).*$' ) || event.request.url.match( '^.*(\/app/mapa\/).*$' ) || event.request.url.match( '^.*(\/app/visita\/).*$' ) || event.request.url.match( '^.*(\/static\/).*$' )){
        event.respondWith(
        caches.match(event.request).then(function(response) {
          if (response) {
            return response;
          }
          return fetch(event.request).then(function(response) {
            if (response.status === 404) {
              return caches.match('internet-error.html');
            }
            return caches.open(staticCacheName).then(function(cache) {
              if (event.request.url.indexOf('test') < 0) {
                cache.put(event.request.url, response.clone());
              }
              return response;
            });
          });
        }).catch(function(error) {
          //console.log('Error, ', error);
          return caches.match('internet-error.html');
        })
      );
    }else{
      false
    }
  });
  self.addEventListener('activate', function(event) {
    console.log('Activando service worker...');
    var cacheWhitelist = [staticCacheName];
    event.waitUntil(
      caches.keys().then(function(cacheNames) {
        return Promise.all(
          cacheNames.map(function(cacheName) {
            if (cacheWhitelist.indexOf(cacheName) === -1) {
              console.log("Eliminando"+cacheName);
              return caches.delete(cacheName);
            }
          })
        );
      })
    );
  });
})();
```

and this is the script that activates such service worker on index.html

```
{% if browser_mobile %}
  if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
    window.addEventListener('load', function() {
      navigator.serviceWorker.register("{% url 'sw.js' %}")
      .then(function(registration){
        console.log('Registré el Service Worker: Paso a redirección',registration.scope);
        if (window.matchMedia('(display-mode: standalone)').matches) {
          var url = "{% url 'autentificacion:inicio' %}";
          window.location = url
        }else{
          console.log("This is NOT! running as standalone.");
        }
      })
      .catch(function(err){
        console.log('Falló la instalación del Service Worker: ', err);
      });
    });
  }
{% else %}
```

Is there something wrong with this service worker? is there a way to debug IOS service worker install? similar to chrome-dev tools?

Comment: Nevermind, as you can see in my code I duplicate an entry in the cache list, once I got rid of it service worker started working as expected, lesson learned I guess.

Comment: I am facing the same problem here and I have no duplicated entries. Were you able to debug your iOS pwa like chrome-dev tools?

Comment: I'm also not seeing my service-worker loaded on ipad safari.. anyone knows how to debug this?

Comment: I'm having the same issue. I don't have a mac to use for accessing any kind of developer tools to see if the SW's are running on my iPad or not (SW's are still listed in "experimental WebKit Features")

Comment: Has anyone figured this out? I'm using workbox, and it seems the service worker registers but gets stuck.. never actually caching anything..on Android everything works as expected..